# How to apply custom function to two dataframe by cell / element?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I apply function f to df1 and df2 by each cell / element?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]], columns=['a','b','c'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[10,10,10],[20,20,20],[30,30,30]], columns=['a','b','c'])

def f(a,b):return(a+b+1)
```

Comment: So `a` is here a cell from `df1`, and `b` the corresponding cell of `df2`?

Comment: Two dataframe have same columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`np.vectorize`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) the function `f`:

```
from numpy import vectorize

fvec = vectorize(f)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(fvec(df1, df2), columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
```

It is however important that the columns and indexes are the same (and in the same order) before vectorizing, since numpy will throw away this metadata.

We thus construct a numpy array with the result, and the "*reconstruct*" the index and columns by obtaining these from one of the two dataframes. But the two dataframes thus perhaps first need some *preprocessing*.

The vectorization can happen with an *arbitrary* number of dataframes (so you could define a function `f` that takes for example three elements to elementwise apply to three dataframes), but the same comments as above hold: you first need to make sure that the columns and indexes of the dataframes match.